# Extracting function domain from a finite set of assignments

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, core-language

Suppose we define a function through a finite collection of equalities, e.g.,

`f[1] = 1; f[26] = 321`

and so on. We can extract the set of output values by running

`Values[DownValues[f]]`

which will return the list `{1, 321}`. I'm looking for a similar command which will instead return the set of inputs I've defined, which in this example would be `{1, 26}`. This isn't an association, so these aren't keys - is there another way to pull out the set of values for which `f` is defined?

Comment: `Cases[DownValues[f], f[x_] :> x, Infinity]`

Comment: `DownValues[f][[All, 1]]`?